# Conversion from string "UNITID, INSTNM, ADDR, CITY, STAB" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am geting the error:

```
InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code

Conversion from string "UNITID, INSTNM, ADDR, CITY, STAB" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

### jcolebrand edited to link to a gist because the code is REALLY long, feel free to fork: https://gist.github.com/2788975

The file is a .csv going into a SQL Database.

Comment: Please show only relevant code, and format it properly (use the Code Sample button)

Comment: your error tells you exactly what you are doing wrong, what do you need help with?

Comment: @jcolebrand The comment was intended as a gentle hint to reexamine his/own question and hopefully improve the quality on his/her own. As it stood it was a bit of a mess.

Comment: @jcolebrand Personally I read through it enough to see there was way to much code here and I wasn't going to spend twenty minutes trying to parse it out in my head, and assumed that would be most peoples reaction, so leaving a link to the questioner to the appropriate meta post seemed an appropriate action to take.  To Mr Train_Wreck -  The biggest tip I can give you is this - High quality questions are more likely to get high quality answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things that I noticed from the error message and from your code. I hope this helps you.

1. Use parameters. [Here is a link to some resources](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=vb.net%20parameterized%20query&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=2eea1a31cbf97609&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1229&bih=828)
2. The specific error you're receiving is tangentially related to #1. The error says that you're attempting to coerce incompatible data types. Specifically, it tells you that you're trying to cram the specific string, `"UNITID, INSTNM, ADDR, CITY, STAB"` into an Integer column.

Given what I've inferred from your schema, these are actually columns so you're missing a few commas along the way. If you were to use parameters, it would (a) clean the code up quite, (b) reduce the security risk, (c) force you to clearly understand the data types with which you're dealing.